# User Yii::t() value for arrays values

Tags: php, yii, internationalization

i´m in a proyect with yii php framework and in muy model i have a public static array with some constante as index like this:

```
const ESTADO_ACTIVA    = 1;
const ESTADO_RECHAZADA = 2;
const ESTADO_ACEPTADA  = 3;
public static $estados = array(
    self::ESTADO_ACTIVA    => 'Activa',
    self::ESTADO_RECHAZADA => 'Rechazada',
    self::ESTADO_ACEPTADA  => 'Aceptada'
);
```

I need replace 'Activa' with  this

```
    const ESTADO_ACTIVA    = 1;
const ESTADO_RECHAZADA = 2;
const ESTADO_ACEPTADA  = 3;
public static $estados = array(
    self::ESTADO_ACTIVA    => Yii::t('category','Activa'),
    self::ESTADO_RECHAZADA => Yii::t('category','Rechazada'),
    self::ESTADO_ACEPTADA  => Yii::t('category','Aceptada'),
);
```

When i try it i get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

I don´t understand what´s wrong. 
Thanks for all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this Yii way (like in docs) i would create estados method:

```
const ESTADO_ACTIVA    = 1;
const ESTADO_RECHAZADA = 2;
const ESTADO_ACEPTADA  = 3;
public static function estados()
{
    return array(
        self::ESTADO_ACTIVA    => Yii::t('category','Activa'),
        self::ESTADO_RECHAZADA => Yii::t('category','Rechazada'),
        self::ESTADO_ACEPTADA  => Yii::t('category','Aceptada'),
    );
}
```

This way you dont need to instantiate class.

**EDIT:** If you don't want to evaluate `Yii::t` at each call, use cached version:

```
const ESTADO_ACTIVA    = 1;
const ESTADO_RECHAZADA = 2;
const ESTADO_ACEPTADA  = 3;

private static $_estados = null;

public static function estados()
{
    if(null === self::$_estados)
    {
        self::$_estados = array(
            self::ESTADO_ACTIVA    => Yii::t('category','Activa'),
            self::ESTADO_RECHAZADA => Yii::t('category','Rechazada'),
            self::ESTADO_ACEPTADA  => Yii::t('category','Aceptada'),
        );
    }
    return self::$_estados;
}
```

With this approach `Yii::t` calls are evaluated only once.

Comment: is perfect but my problem is i call classname::$Estados from many view .. can i initialized it in "model function" .. i think yes but prefer answer.. or you recomend call __constructor?

Comment: If you already used many classname::$estados use decent IDE like [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and search and replace in files. With my method you call it in view with classname::estados(), not a big difference. I updated my answer to add cached version too - to deal better with many calls.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you cannot initialize an array with non-constant expressions. Calling `Yii::t` is such an expression, which means that you have to compute the final form of `$estados` inside a method body.

For example, you could do that inside the constructor:

```
public static $estados;

public function __construct()
{
    if (!self::$estados) {
        self::$estados = array(
            self::ESTADO_ACTIVA    => Yii::t('category','Activa'),
            self::ESTADO_RECHAZADA => Yii::t('category','Rechazada'),
            self::ESTADO_ACEPTADA  => Yii::t('category','Aceptada'),
        );
    }
}
```